# Bash if statement to check for like 1 letter and 2 numbers

Tags: regex, bash, if-statement, digits, alphabetical

Need some help with a script.  I am trying to make sure the user enters a valid school term, like `F18`, `F19` etc.

The letters that can be used are `F`, `S`, `M`, `N` (which are Fall, Spring, Summer, Special) the numbers are years, `18`, `19`, `20`, `21` etc.

The problem with my current setup if someone mistyped for example `ff18`, it's correct, or `f181` it's correct. I want it to only accept 1 letter and 2 numbers.

```
#!/bin/bash

term_arg=$1
letter_range="[f|F|s|S|m|M|n|N]"
number_range="[10-99]"
if [[ "${term_arg}" = "" ]] || ! [[ "${term_arg}" =~ ${letter_range}${number_range} ]]; then
  echo "Please specify a valid term: e.g. F18, S19, M19, etc. "
  exit 1
else
  echo "The term id ${term_arg} is correct"
  exit 0
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Square brackets introduce character classes, so

```
[f|F]
```

matches any of the three characters: `f`, `|`, or `F`.

Similarly,

```
[10-99]
```

matches `1`, `0` to `9`, and `9`, which is equivalent to `[0-9]` or `[0123456789]`.

So, you need

```
[fFsSmMnN][0-9][0-9]
```

Note that this works with plain `=`, too, no need to use regular expressions, as the right hand side is interpreted as a pattern unless quoted:

```
$ [[ m18 = [fsmn][0-9][0-9] ]] && echo matches
matches
```

Comment: That worked a treat, however, if I want to limited them from entering no earlier than 10 and not later than 30?  Also, if I wanted to add the words fall, spring, summer etc in any case as well.  so that incase someone wanted to enter summer19 because they can't remember that M is for summer, how would that look?

Comment: Maybe look into `extglob`: `@(fall|spring|summer|special)` or use a regular expression. Also, no need to check everything in one step, extract the number in one step, check its value in another step.

Comment: Have a look at my answer below.  It addresses everything except for the range of (10 <= year <= 30), but you can just change the regex to yearRegex='[12][0-9]|30', which means the year is between 10-29, or the number 30.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use Google, since there are a lot of examples of how to do an exact match.  A regex matches *characters*, not *numbers*.  Pay particular attention to how the numeric part is examined.  I've added capture groups to get the quarter and year to assign those parts to variables, and I am upper-casing the input so that you don't have to worry about matching case.  This also shows how to add individual words that you want to check.  And you can separate the quarter and the year with a space or a dash, or neither and it handles the input of these cases just fine.

Try:

```
#!/bin/bash

term_arg=$@
quarterRegex='FALL|SPRING|SUMMER|SPECIAL'
quarterAbbrevRegex='[FSMN]'
yearRegex='[1-9][0-9]'
separatorRegex='(-|[[:space:]])?'
termRegex="^(${quarterAbbrevRegex}|${quarterRegex})${separatorRegex}(${yearRegex})$"
declare termEntry
declare yearEntry
if [[ "${term_arg^^}" =~ $termRegex ]]; then
  termEntry="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  yearEntry="${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
  echo "The term id ${term_arg} is correct:"
  echo "  Term: ${termEntry}"
  echo "  Year: ${yearEntry}"
  exit 0
else
  echo "${term_arg} is in an incorrect format.  Please specify a valid term: e.g., F18, S19, M19, etc."
  exit 1
fi
```